# Does Carto.js v4.2 support Named Maps?

Tags: carto, carto.js

I was trying to update my carto.js code from v3.15.19 to v4.2. What I recognized that carto.js v4.2 is no longer supports Named Maps. 
I researched a lot and checking into the documentation made me wonder that there is no Named Maps mentioned at all inside the documentation for V4.2.
So please can anyone confirm if there is still any way to add NamedMaps layers to the map using carto.js v4.2 or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CARTO.js v4 does not support Named Maps. The most similar feature is [using the Auth API giving Maps `Select` permissions](https://carto.com/developers/auth-api/guides/CARTO-Authorization/).